# Retain custom string value set by OnClick event across swipes with SwipeAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, swipe, retain

Im using a SwipeAdapter to populate a Fragment on an Activity.
I want to hide certain items on the Fragment when I tap on the Screen.|

Like "Testing flashcards"

Problem is, every time is swipe, my "isHidden" value is reset back to False.

How do I retain this value between swipes?

SavedSessionState doesn't seem to be saving the value, when I set the value in the touch event, the app crashes.

```
     view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (hidden) {
                case "True":{
                    hidden = "False";

                    savedInstanceState.putString("hidden2",hidden);
                    break;
                }
                case "False":{
                    hidden = "True";

                    savedInstanceState.putString("hidden2",hidden);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

App crashes or isHidden value is reset back to False.
isHidden is initialised when Fragment loads as a 
public String isHidden = "False"
(I had it on bool and just got desperate)

Comment: Anyone? I still have not figured this out